# Nodemailer Gmail Authentication Issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, gmail, nodemailer

I'm trying to use Nodemailer in a Node.js application to send emails via Gmail. However, I'm encountering an authentication issue with the error message "Missing credentials for 'PLAIN'." I've reviewed my code and environment variables, and everything seems correct.

```
// Import nodemailer module
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

// Create a transporter using Gmail SMTP
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.ADDRESS,
    pass: process.env.MAILING_SERVICE_APP_PASSWORD,
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false, 
  },
});

// Function to send an email
async function sendEmail(to: string, subject: string, text: string) {
  // Email options
  const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.ADDRESS,
    to: to,
    subject: subject,
    text: text,
  };

  // Send email
  return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
}

// Export the sendEmail function
export default sendEmail;
```

I've double-checked my environment variables, and I have set an App password for this gmail account. However, I'm still getting the same error. Can someone help me identify the issue with my Nodemailer setup?

Here is the entire error message:

```
[0] 2:49:04 PM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
[1] POST /register 200 149.764 ms - 475
[1] Error sending email:  Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"
[1]     at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\zsomb\OneDrive\Desktop\University\Projects\DataProcessing-BackEnd\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:790:19)
[1]     at SMTPConnection.login (C:\Users\zsomb\OneDrive\Desktop\University\Projects\DataProcessing-BackEnd\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:444:38)
[1]     at C:\Users\zsomb\OneDrive\Desktop\University\Projects\DataProcessing-BackEnd\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:272:32
[1]     at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zsomb\OneDrive\Desktop\University\Projects\DataProcessing-BackEnd\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:213:17)
[1]     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:28)
[1]     at SMTPConnection.emit (node:events:514:28)
[1]     at SMTPConnection._actionEHLO (C:\Users\zsomb\OneDrive\Desktop\University\Projects\DataProcessing-BackEnd\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1347:14)
[1]     at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\zsomb\OneDrive\Desktop\University\Projects\DataProcessing-BackEnd\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:969:20)
[1]     at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\zsomb\OneDrive\Desktop\University\Projects\DataProcessing-BackEnd\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:755:14)
[1]     at SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\zsomb\OneDrive\Desktop\University\Projects\DataProcessing-BackEnd\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:193:44) {
[1]   code: 'EAUTH',
[1]   command: 'API'
[1] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I am using the only diffrence is the port i think

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
async function main() {
    // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
    // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
    let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: '[REDACTED]',
            pass: '[Apps password redacted]',
        },
    });

    // send mail with defined transport object
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: '"Linda Lawton " <[REDACTED]>', // sender address
        to: "[REDACTED]", // list of receivers
        subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
        text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
        html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
    });

    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);

    // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

}

main().catch(console.error);
```

I did try chaning my point to 465 and setting secure to true and adding the tls.  still works.